# Python dictionary is empty after looping

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
    v1    v2    v3
    a    b     a,b
    b    a     b,a
    c    a     c,a
```

I am trying to iterate over the v3 column to create a dictionary that counts the unique string combinations. In the loop, I need to check on existing combinations and reverse combinations to count them as the same (i.e `a,b` is same as `b,a`).

Here is the code that I have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")

combine_count = {}
col = df['v3']
for entry in col:
    if entry in combine_count.keys():
        combine_count[entry] += 1
    elif entry not in combine_count.keys():
        reverse = ','.join(entry.split(',')[::-1])
        if reverse in combine_count.keys():
            combine_count[entry] += 1
    else:
        combine_count[entry] = 1
```

The output after `print(combine_count)` is an empty dictionary `{}`. How do I collect the proper keys and values?

Comment: Is the posted code indented the same as what you ran?

Comment: The code doesn't even run - the indentation of `else`s is kind of important!

Comment: *(Assuming your indentation in actual code is correct)* You need to put some print statement in the code for debugging it. What I may tell you is that one of your `if` statement without `else` is failing

Comment: @Brad Boldenow Definitely correct the indentation in your question, otherwise you'll keep getting comments about that, which distracts from your question. Assuming it isn't currently correct, of course. If it is, your code with not run, thus no empty dictionary.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the feedback. I fixed the indentation.

Comment: You cannot get past `elif entry not in combine_count.keys():`. Since that case is `True` but `if reverse in combine_count.keys():` is `False`, nothing ever gets added to the dictionary. You need to indent the `Else` clause one more level.

Comment: Either `entry in combine_count.keys()` is true or `entry not in combine_count.keys()` is true, but never are both conditions false, so your else is never reached. And because of that you never enter anything into `combine_count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-frozenset):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> cnts = Counter(frozenset(item.split(',')) for item in df['v3'])
>>> cnts
Counter({frozenset({'a', 'b'}): 2, frozenset({'a', 'c'}): 1})
```

a `Counter` can be used like any dictionary and the `frozenset` takes care that the order doesn't matter, just the contents.

You could also convert this back to a plain dictionary with string-keys:

```
>>> {','.join(sorted(key)): count for key, count in cnts.items()}
{'a,b': 2, 'a,c': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two logical problems to fix in your code. 1) the last `else` statement is not indented correctly, in your original code it will never get executed, since the `if` and `elif` covered all the possible cases (a key can either in the dictionary or not); 2) if `reverse` in `combine_count.keys()` you should add one to `reverse`, since `entry` is not in the dictionary but the `reverse`.

```
combine_count = {}
col = df['v3']
for entry in col:
    if entry in combine_count.keys():
        combine_count[entry] += 1

    elif entry not in combine_count.keys():
        reverse = ','.join(entry.split(',')[::-1])

        if reverse in combine_count.keys():
            combine_count[reverse] += 1          # entry to reverse

        else:                                    # indentation here
            combine_count[entry] = 1

dict(combine_count)
# {'a,b': 2, 'c,a': 1}
```

---

Besides since you are using `pandas`, here is another `pandas/numpy` approach:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# here use maximum and minimum to sort your key before doing any count
(np.minimum(df.v1, df.v2) + "," + np.maximum(df.v1, df.v2)).value_counts().to_dict()

# {'a,b': 2, 'a,c': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, I believe, is this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")

combine_count = {}
col = df['v3']
for entry in col:
    if col[entry] in combine_count.keys():
        combine_count[col[entry]] += 1
    elif col[entry] not in combine_count.keys():
        reverse = ','.join(col[entry].split(',')[::-1])
        if reverse in combine_count.keys():
            combine_count[reverse] += 1
        else:        
            combine_count[col[entry]] = 1
```

What you want to do is check for the presence of the `value`, say `a,b` for example, not the `key`. For the purposes of comparison, the `key` is irrelevant, at least as far as I understand your intentions. So rather than check for `entry`, you want to be checking for `col[entry]`.

Fixing that, and with the code using proper indentation as I've illustrated here, you should be good to go. This will return each value, including any mirror images, and the count of each value, as a dictionary.

To collect the keys, you can use the values from this dictionary to create a list, say, of all the keys in col that associate with that value.